# Will a disabled text field submit when a form is POSTed?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, form-submit

If I submit a disabled text field via POST, what will the resulting value be on the action page?

For example, I have:

```
<table border=0 cellpadding=4 cellspacing=0>
<tr><td>
   <input type="checkbox" id="chk_$item" 
    onClick="javascript:handleClick('$item')">
</td><td>
   <input type="text" id="txt_$item" name="addresses[]" value="$item">
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
   ...etc...
</td></tr>
</table>
```

the `handleClick()` javascript function checks if `chk_$item` is checked, if not, it disables the `txt_$item` text field.

When I submit it, all of the text fields go to an `addresses[]` array in a PHP script.

But, can I prevent the field from submitting anything if it is disabled? Will it do this by default? If not, how should I change the behavior? (I really don't want to clear the fields when they get disabled).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Disabled inputs will not be submitted with the form; that's part of the defined behavior of `disabled`, cf. [W3C HTML 4.01 Form docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1).

Answer (score 25):

If you don't want it changed, make it `readonly`.

Comment: Simply put: read-only does *not* fulfill the OP's demand. If I understand correct, the OP explicitly wanted to exclude fields from submit. Sounds similar, but essentially this is an entirely different thing. It's not about protecting field content at the client side but about reducing submission data set received at the server side. chaos suggested *disabled* inputs. I know from earlier tests, that 'read-only' and 'disabled' even looks different in different web browsers, and is in fact not the same.

Comment: This would be better written as a comment and read "Or, if you don't want it changed...". It doesn't satisfy OP's question. It's alternative solution to an alternative problem.