# Add/Remove Inputs within a Form Dependent on Checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, forms, input, checkbox

I have a form with 3 check boxes and a text area under each checkbox.

HTML:

```
<form>
<input class="checkbox" id="checkboxsection1" type="checkbox" name="section1">Section 1<br/>
<textarea name="section1textarea"> Sample </textarea><br/>

 <input class="checkbox" id="checkboxsection2" type="checkbox" name="section2">Section 2<br/>
     <textarea name="section2textarea"> Sample </textarea><br/>

 <input class="checkbox" id="checkboxsection3" type="checkbox" name="section3">Section 3<br/>
     <textarea name="section3textarea"> Sample </textarea><br/>

 <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grapien/xvZ6F/)

The way I have the code now is that the textarea is hidden when the checkbox is unchecked and visible when the checkbox is checked using jqueryUI toggle function.

The code I am working with is more complicated then above (I have simplified it for purposes of this question), but in my circumstance I cannot remove the textarea as I have canvas elements and javascript that call on it and rely on it for input. If more information is needed I will add more complexity to the code above.

Upon submit of the form everything is passed to a shopping cart. I was wondering if there is anyway to prevent the textarea from being passed to the shopping cart if the above checkbox above that textarea remains unchecked, without actually removing the textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this question's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215641/will-a-disabled-text-field-submit-when-a-form-is-posted), disabled fields do not get posted.

You can disable a textarea by calling:

```
$('textarea[name=section1textarea]').prop('disabled', true);
```

And re-enable it by calling:

```
$('textarea[name=section1textarea]').prop('disabled', false);
```

**UPDATE**

I just want to add that the checkbox values will get posted when they are checked, so I would just ignore a posted textarea value when the corresponding checkbox is not checked, and not bother with disabling the textareas. Or do both just be to safe.

Comment: Thanks for the direction, I did not see that post in my search but I appreciate the help!

Comment: Thanks for the update I appreciate it, just put the code into my website and it worked perfectly!